# Como estender um DIV até o fim da tela?

Tags: html, css

Bom criei um div principal para comportar todos os elementos da página. Dentro dele tenho 3 outros `divs`: 1 barra de menu, 1 barra lateral, 1 area de conteudo.

HTML:

```
<div class="principal">
  <div class="barra_menu">
    Barra de menu
  </div>
  <div class="menu_lateral">
    <!--Como se estende esse div até o fim da página/elemento pai-->
    Menu lateral:<br>.<br>.<br>.
  </div>
  <div class="area_conteudo">
    Area de conteudo:<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.principal{background-color:red;height:100%;}
.barra_menu{background-color:gray;widht:100%;}
.menu_lateral{background-color:blue;width:30%;float:left;}
.area_conteudo{background-color:green;width:70%;float:left;}
```

Eu quero que o menu lateral se estenda da posição de onde ele se encontra até o fim da página, mas não sei a solução.

Gostaria de obter uma solução baseada apenas em HTML/CSS preferencialmente sem utilizar posicionamento absoluto.

A seguir um exemplo visual do que eu quero fazer: https://jsfiddle.net/m17wuaLc/2/

Answer (score 1):

Lhe recomendo utilizar a técnica do [Sticky Footer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/), caso haja necessidade de compatibilidade com navegadores antigos.

Sua estrutura HTML ficaria assim:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
.side-left{
  float:left;
  width: 30%;
}
.content{
  float:left;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <div class="side-left">
    Menu
  </div>
  
  <div class="content">
    Content!
  </div>
      
</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  I'm the Sticky Footer.
</footer>
```

Comment: Pode adicionar um exemplo de uso na reposta?

Comment: Sim, claro. Mas o link tem os detalhes completo.

Comment: É porque resposta com links apenas não estão dentro do tipo de resposta que o site aceita como positiva. Para que sirva de referencia no futuro, caso este link deixe de existir, seria interessante ter um exemplo de uso na resposta também.

Comment: Pronto, exemplo incluso.

Comment: achei essa técnica muito interessante, mas o que estou fazendo aqui não tem um rodapé fixo, é um layout que se assemelha a de um aplicativo

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar a propriedade:

> 1vh (viewport height) = 1% of viewport height

vai ficar assim

```
min-height:100vh;
```

Comment: o menu lateral  não se localiza no topo da página, há uma barra vertical antes dele. ao aplicar a propiedade proposta o menu é estendido além do limite da tela. Procuro uma solução que estenda o menu da posição onde ele se encontra até o fim da tela

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente você deve dar ao **body** um

```
height: 100%
```

E a seu menu lateral-direito, o mesmo. Ficaria assim:

```
body{
   height: 100%
}
.menu_lateral{
   height: 100%;
}
```

O **body** possui de padrão um 
     height: auto

Devido a isso o body se estenderá ao tamanho do maior elemento. Dando um ***height: 100%*** isso será desfeito e ele terá o tamanho da tela.

Comment: o detalhe que o menu lateral não se localiza no topo da página, há uma barra de menu antes dele. De modo que se aplicar um height 100% no menu lateral será considerado o tamanho da body relativo a posição que ele se localiza, o que estende o menu lateral além do limite da tela/elemento-pai

Comment: eu queria que pegasse da posição que ele se encontra até o fim da tela

Comment: Olhe esse jsfiddle, se for o que queria, explico em detalhes o que fiz. https://jsfiddle.net/m17wuaLc/6/

Comment: samir braga, acaba entrando no problema de todas as respostas até aqui, como há uma barra de menu antes do menu lateral é atribuido ao elemento o height:100% considerando a posição que o elemento se encontra, esticando o menu além do limite da tela... compare o seu exemplo com este: https://jsfiddle.net/m17wuaLc/7/

Comment: Não entendo a que se refere, se está se referindo ao fato do barra lateral ultrapassar o menu, isso não aconteceu no meu exemplo. Até mesmo quando atribuo um height ao menu superior. Olhe https://jsfiddle.net/m17wuaLc/8/ .